# How can reverse('opensearch') work in the shell, but fails in a Test?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-testing, opensearch

I'm trying to install django-lean into my application.

Open search is used in my app App.

I can reverse('opensearch') in the Python shell. However, in the test, reverse('opensearch') * NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'opensearch' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments

```
In [47]: reverse('opensearch')
Out[47]: '/opensearch.xml'
In [48]: response = client.get('/opensearch.xml')
In [49]: response.status_code
Out[49]: 200
```

This is an attempt to do the same from the Test, stopped by pdb.set_trace()

```
No fixtures found.
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_lean-0.15-py2.7.egg/django_lean/experiments/tests/test_tags.py(72)doTestIntegration()
-> response = client.get("confirm_human") # this is where the Client can't find the url
(Pdb) reverse('opensearch')
*** NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'opensearch' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Here is the code from urls.py:

```
url(r'^opensearch\.xml$', app.meta.opensearch, name='opensearch'),
```

Finally, here is the traceroute for the failing test:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: testIntegrationWithRegisteredUser (django_lean.experiments.tests.test_tags.ExperimentTagsTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_lean-0.15-py2.7.egg/django_lean/experiments/tests/test_tags.py", line 55, in testIntegrationWithRegisteredUser
    client_factory=create_registered_user_client)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_lean-0.15-py2.7.egg/django_lean/experiments/tests/test_tags.py", line 71, in doTestIntegration
    response = client.get(confirm_human_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/test/client.py", line 290, in get
    response = self.request(**r)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/test/client.py", line 230, in request
    response = self.handler(environ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/test/client.py", line 74, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 142, in get_response
    return self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/views/defaults.py", line 24, in server_error
    return http.HttpResponseServerError(t.render(Context({})))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/__init__.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/test/utils.py", line 29, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/__init__.py", line 796, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/__init__.py", line 809, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 125, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/test/utils.py", line 29, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/__init__.py", line 796, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/__init__.py", line 809, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 378, in render
    raise e
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'opensearch' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1736.834s
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might be [Bug 11077](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11077).  If so, the problem is a TestCase overriding the urlconf, as noted there in [this comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11077#comment:4): "The problem lies with the fact that the tests for both django.contrib.auth and django-registration set their  TestCase.urls setting to override the default URLConf."